How to use DynamoDB data?
I'm trying to do stuff with my DynamoDB data, but my IDE is complaining about types.
From the documentation, it looks like an example response from the DB would be data like:
{
    "Item": {
        "AlbumTitle": {
            "S": "Songs About Life"
        },
        "Awards": {
            "S": "10"
        },
        "Artist": {
            "S": "Acme Band"
        },
        "SongTitle": {
            "S": "Happy Day"
        }
    }
}

I would assume that I would access the album title by accessing data.Item.AlbumTitle.S. However for my code I am destructuring:
import {GetItemCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const getFromDb = async (albumTitle: string) => {
  const command = new GetItemCommand({
    TableName: "table-name",
    Key: {
      AlbumTitle: { S: albumTitle }
    }
  });

  return await client.send(command);
};

const dbRes = await getFromDb('some-album');
const {AlbumTitle, Awards, Artist, SongTitle} = dbRes?.Item;

The IDE throws red over all of the destructured variable names, stating:
TS2339: Property AlbumTitle does not exist on type Record<string, AttributeValue> | undefined

If we assume that I will retrieve correct data and I get an album back... how do I use this data?
I assume again that I'd be accessing the Artist with dbRes.Item.Artist.S?

What's unclear from the error? What should happen if dbRes?.Item is undefined? (Also not sure why the optional chaining to begin with: dbRes is definitely going to exist, according to the types.)

@jonrsharpe sorry, I've updated the end of my question.
Assume we are getting data back from the DB... I'm just struggling with how to use it.

That doesn't answer my question. Read the output: the types you've been supplied say dbRes.Item might be undefined, so you cannot reliably destructure it (it would be a TypeError, exactly the sort of thing TypeScript is trying to help you avoid). So what should your code do in that case? You need to decide that, then implement it.

Ah I got you! Brain fart. I just added || {} after the dbRes.Item in the destructure ;-)

The compiler does not know for certain if your parameters exist for that given object in the response. You should implement an interface or type assertion for the item object.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions
Or just add a simple check:
if (dbRes.Item && 'AlbumTitle' in dbRes.Item) {
  const { AlbumTitle, Awards, Artist, SongTitle } = dbRes.Item;

  const albumTitle = AlbumTitle.S;
  const awards = Awards.S;
  const artist = Artist.S;
  const songTitle = SongTitle.S;

  console.log(albumTitle, awards, artist, songTitle);
} else {
  console.error("Item not found in the database");
}


Good to know that Item will always be returned

I think, this is not true. The docs say "if there is no matching item, GetItem does not return any data and there will be no Item element in the response." Also, in the GetItemOutput type, Item is an optional.
